# gcloud logging with regular expression

Tags: gcloud, google-cloud-logging

I'm trying to use `gcloud logging` along with regular expression. My query works in the console but I can't get it going via the CLI.

```
gcloud logging read "resource.type=gce_instance AND protoPayload.authenticationInfo.principalEmail=~'.*@example.com.au'" --limit=10 --format=json
```

I get the error:

```
ERROR: (gcloud.logging.read) INVALID_ARGUMENT: Unparseable filter: unrecognized node at token 'MEMBER'
```

I've tried with and without various quotes `'' "" "\"\`

I also have the same trouble when doing timestamp dates as well:

```
gcloud logging read "resource.type=gce_instance AND timestamp > '2021-06-15T00:00:00.000000Z'"
```

I get the error:

```
ERROR: (gcloud.logging.read) INVALID_ARGUMENT: Unparseable filter: syntax error at line 1, column 112, token ':';
```

Comment: I'm getting the same error. Can you update your question with more details about how you're doing this using console ?

Comment: @Wojtek_B using Cloud Logging via the console my query would look like: `resource.type="gce_instance" AND protoPayload.authenticationInfo.principalEmail =~ ".*@example.com.au"`. My intent is to find active users in projects that shouldn't be used. The above doesn't work within the python SDK.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your first `gcloud` expression should look like this:

```
cloud logging read "resource.type=gce_instance AND protoPayload.authenticationInfo.principalEmail:'.*@example.com.au'"
```

I changed `=` sign to `:`.

And the second one like this:

```
gcloud logging read 'resource.type=gce_instance AND timestamp > "2021-08-15T00:00:00.000000Z"'
```

I exchanged single with double quotes (literally).

It's best to have a quick look at the [gcloud logging read command documentation](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/logging/read) (I figured out a proper syntax this way).

Comment: Thanks again. I spent half the day learning Cloud Logging queries via the console then tried to jump into using gcloud and just hit a block. But looks like each has its own variation of the language.